# In mvc4 of net4, try to invoke the result of asynchronous method in synchronization method, deadlock occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

In mvc4 of net4, try to invoke the result of asynchronous method in synchronization method, deadlock occurs.

1. I want it to run synchronously

```
public  RespData PushMsg(string tel, int push_type, int push_type_sub, string alert, string title, string content, string href)
{
    var result = Push.HMSPushV3(tel, push_type, push_type_sub, alert, title, content, href).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return reuslt;
}
```

2. This is the asynchronous method being called

```
public async static Task<RespData> HMSPushV3(string tel, int push_type, int push_type_sub, string alert, string title, string content, string href)
{
    RespData r = new RespData();
    string[] arr = tel.Split(',');
    try
    {
        var device_token_list = Push.GetPolicy().GetHMSPushDeviceToken(arr);
        var data = new PushModel() 
        { 
            alert = alert, content = content, href = href, push_type = push_type, title = title, push_type_sub_enum = push_type_sub 
        };

        {
            //Locked up in this place
            var messageId = await HMSPush.SendToData(device_token_list, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
            r.Msg = $"透传:msgId {messageId}";
        }
        {
            var message = HMSPush.CreateAndroidMessage(data);
            var messageId = await HMSPush.SendToNotification(device_token_list, message);
            r.Msg += $"  通知栏:msgId {messageId}";
        }
        r.State = 1;
        r.Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        DB.FileLog.Error(e.Message, e);
        r.Msg = e.Message;
        r.State = 0;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` to your async method that you are awaiting.

This method does not mean that the call will not be awaited, just that it doesn't have to be continued on the same thread:

```
var messageId = await HMSPush.SendToData(device_token_list, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data))
                                 .ConfigureAwait(false);
```